# How to handle large navigation titles with uitabbarcontroller in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am designing the app with bottom master menu by using uitabbar controller. my tabbarcontroller is embed in uinavigationcontroller and in tabbar controller having 5 view controllers.
and i am using large titles of navigation with search bar and I am getting accurate result when i am landing of first page when I am switching the tabs the navigation large titles getting stuck not scrolling up.
Also I only want seach bar on 2 viewcontrollers not on all.

Thank You!

Comment: Please show us storyboard images.

Comment: Its resolved already :) I put each an every view controller in separate UINavigationController and put those all navigations controllers in single tab bar view controller then my problem was fixed. thank you